# give a combobox in Excel a default selected value with VBA

Tags: vba, excel-2007

I have a combobox in Excel created as the picture suggests, and it has a range associated to it.

How can I give it a default value from this range, through VBA?

```
ActiveSheet.Shapes("DropDown1").ControlFormat.Value = "Germany"
```

I tried the above code, but it doesn't work. I believe the syntax is not correct. Can you please help?
Thank you!
[image]

Comment: Your picture isn't there.

Comment: I readded it, I hope it is visible now, Doug, thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the DropDown type, it doesn't show up in the intellisence when you type.

```
Dim DropDown1 As DropDown
Set DropDown1 = ActiveSheet.DropDowns("DropDown1")

DropDown1.Value = 1
```

The value is the index of the dropdown, so 1 is the first in the list etc. Use 0 to have no value selected. Also make sure the name "DropDown1" is the correct name for the control, if you right click the control in the excel sheet you'll see the name for the control to the left of the function bar.

Comment: +1 beat me to it. I think the default naming is `Drop Down 1` (with spaces) but good note for OP to double-check the spelling of this.

Comment: Is it possible to always have intellisence activated? Thank you to both very much!

Comment: @David Lol, while i was typing I expect someone to answer before me :P

Comment: @Sam If you open the **Object Browser** while in the VBA editor (its a shortcut button on the same line as the run button, or just push F2) then right click on object browser's screen and click **Show Hidden Members** Then things like the DropDown member will show up in the intellisence. Though when using the **ActiveSheet** no intellisense tends to show up on it, so I find it easier to declare a worksheet variable and assign it to the sheet you working on